# Applying a function to a specific element of a list of a list

Tags: r

I have a function that returns a list of vectors and matrices. I then create a variable that is a list of several of the resulting lists from calls to the function. So I have a list of lists. My question is how do I apply a function over the elements of these lists (note this is not the same as applying a function over the lists themselves). Here is a simple example that retains all the essential features of what I am doing

```
numtrials = 5

x = rep(list(NULL),numtrials)

testfunction = function(){return( list( c(1,2,3,4,5), matrix(runif(10), 2,5),
                                    matrix(0,2,2) ) )}

for(index in 1:numtrials){
    x[[index]] = testfunction()
}
```

I want to now calculate the mean of say the (2,3) element of `x[[index]][[2]]` across all "index" lists. Or even better get a matrix of means, `xbar`, such that `xbar[i,j] = mean(x[[]][[2]][i,j])`.  I tried to play around with (and of course read the help file for) `lapply`,  and `apply`, but couldn't get it to work. One of the reasons is that `x[[]][[2]][i,j]` appears to be invalid notation

```
Error in x[[]] : invalid subscript type 'symbol'
```

I think R doesn't know what to make of the "`[[]]`". I know some people are going to suggest vectorizing but note that my function returns matrices and vectors of different, unrelated dimensions (although I am not opposed to vectorizing if you have a clever way of doing this).

Comment: It might help to include in your post the value for the mean you want for the (2,3) element of x[[index]][[2]].  And include the value(s) you want for the xbar.  That would help others to check whether their code returns what you want.  At least it would help me.

Comment: the matrix is random though so it would depend on your seed, Marius post works for the specific [2,3] example so you could use that code to check the your code for the full matrix of means case by checking the [2,3] element against Marius's code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `abind` you can create a list which contains arrays for the relevent components of the internal lists..

eg

```
library(abind)

xl <- do.call(mapply, c('abind', x, rev.along = 0))


# the second element from each inner list is now within a 3-d array 
# which is the 2nd element of  xl

# you can now construct your matrix of mean values by using `apply`

means <- apply(xl[[2]], 1:2, mean)
means
##            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
## [1,] 0.4576039 0.5185270 0.7099742 0.3812656 0.4529965
## [2,] 0.6528345 0.2304651 0.5534443 0.4404609 0.7361132
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know which elements you want to pull out, then it's pretty straightforward to grab them with `sapply`/`lapply`, and get the mean:

```
# Mean of [[2]][2, 3] elements
values = sapply(x, function(elem) {
  return(elem[[2]][2, 3])
})
mean(values)
```

`sapply` applies a function to each element of the outer list, which is passed in as the `elem` argument to the little anonymous function I've written. Then you just get the 2nd element of each of those: `elem[[2]]`, and index into it to get the `[2, 3]` value.

Comment: this definitely works in the [2,3] case, but is there an easier way of generalizing it beyond looping over the entries of the matrix?

Comment: and by that I mean create a matrix of means of [[2]][i,j] without a loop

Answer (score 0):

here is the code, it may help you, first unlist and then apply on top of it

```
ulist=function(x)
{
  l=length(x)
  for(i in 1:l) lst[[i]]=x[[i]][[2]]
  return(lst)
}

#apply mean of each column of the x[[i]][[2]] matrix
sapply(ulist(x),function(y) apply(y,2,mean))

#apply mean of each row of the x[[i]][[2]] matrix
sapply(ulist(x),function(y) apply(y,1,mean))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this code is giving, it also doesn't produce the correct answer, use Marius's code to look at element 2,3 it doesn't match yours.